# Error Parse 1.9.3 and OkHTTP 2.0.0

Tags: android, parse-platform, okhttp

When I use version 1.9.3 of Parse (Parse-1.9.3.jar) and OkHTTP version 2.0.0 in the same project, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setFollowRedirects(Z)V in class Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient' appears in /data/app/XXXXXXXXXXX/base.apk:classes2.dex)
```

When I downgrade Parse to 1.9.2, everything works fine.
Any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: obviously Parse v1.9.3 was compilled with newer OkHTTP ...

Comment: Why do you say that? Is there a newer version of OkHTTP? If I don't use OkHTTP 2.0.0, everything works fine, so it seems to me, that this lib is overriding the one used on Parse.jar. If this is true, it means the opposite of  what you are saying, that Parse 1.9.3 was compiled with an old version of OkHTTP.

Comment: again, parse 1.9.3 is using OkHttp newer than 2.0.0 ... there was no method setFollowRedirects in OkHttp 2.0.0 [see 2.0.0](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-2.0.0/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.java) [see 2.1.0](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-2.1.0/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.java) ... so solution is to use newer OkHttp version or use Parse 1.9.2

Comment: Ok, makes sense, and it worked. Can you post as an answer, so I can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: What is the solution? I can not upgrade Parse in my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Selvin said, Parse 1.9.3 uses OKHttp 2.1.0 (probably), so if you override it with OKHttp 2.0.0, you will have that error. You have 2 possibilities. Use Parse 1.9.3, and upgrade your OKHttp to some version newer than 2.0.0, or if you cannot upgrade your OKHttp, use Parse 1.9.2 instead.

Comment: I didn't know that my project uses any version of OKHttp until now... and I don't know where it is.

Comment: Maybe you are not using directly OKHttp, but some library you have included, use it. Can you show the list of libraries you are using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a library that depends on an old version of OKHTTP (in my case, it is CreativeSDK), you will have this problem.

I just resolve it importing de last version of OkHTTP in gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
```

Now, Parse is using this version of OkHTTP, while CreativeSDK uses its own version, and both are working.

Comment: @EIYeante I am facing same problem, CreativeSDK and Parse.com